# How to zip a file using cmd line?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, command-prompt

I want to zip a directory using the batch file command (Windows XP batch file).

For example, if I want to unzip a file means I can use the `jar -xf file.zip`(java) bat file command.

Like that I want a command line batch to zip a directory.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Why do you need to use the command line? In what context do you want to use the command - because you tagged this question with Java AND Flex?

Comment: On Windows? Linux? OSX?

Comment: Since OP is talking about "BAT file", then I assume it's Windows.

Comment: Yes, we can zip and unzip the file/folder using cmd. See the below command and simply you can copy past in cmd and change the directory and file name


To Zip/Compress File
`powershell Compress-Archive D:\Build\FolderName D:\Build\FolderName.zip`

To Unzip/Expand File
`powershell expand-archive D:\Build\FileName.zip D:\deployments\FileName`

Answer (score 228, accepted):

### If you are using Ubuntu Linux:

1. Install `zip`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install zip
   ```
2. Zip your folder:

   ```
   zip -r {filename.zip} {foldername}
   ```

### If you are using Microsoft Windows:

Windows does not come with a command-line zip program, despite Windows Explorer natively supporting Zip files since the Plus! pack for Windows 98.

I recommend the open-source 7-Zip utility which includes a command-line executable and supports many different archive file types, especially its own `*.7z` format which offers superior compression ratios to traditional (PKZIP) `*.zip` files:

1. Download 7-Zip from the [7-Zip home page](http://www.7-zip.org/)
2. Add the path to `7z.exe` to your `PATH` environment variable. See this QA: 
   [How to set the path and environment variables in Windows](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm#1)
3. Open a new command-prompt window and use this command to create a PKZIP `*.zip` file:

   ```
   7z a -tzip {yourfile.zip} {yourfolder}
   ```

### Cross-platform Java:

If you have the Java JDK installed then you can use the `jar` utility to create Zip files, as `*.jar` files are essentially just renamed `*.zip` (PKZIP) files:

```
jar -cfM {yourfile.zip} {yourfolder}
```

Explanation:
* -c compress
* -f specify filename
* -M do not include a MANIFEST file

Comment: I am using windows Xp can u suggest?

Comment: when using windows xp: 1. install a zip tool, I suggest 7zip, it's free and support many types, you can download it from [7zip home page](http://www.7-zip.org/), 2. add installition path of 7-zip to your PATH. see detail [How to set the path and environment variables in Windows](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm#1), 3. execute it: 7z a -tzip yourfile.zip yourfolder @user1990589, if you want more examples, [check this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples)

Comment: @user1990589 I imporved my anwser, and an xp way and a java way, hope it helps.

Comment: If you are on Windows, you can also install MinGW, it can allow you you to install `zip`

Comment: Without adding the path, by calling the .exe file directly: C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe a -tzip {yourfile.zip} {yourfolder}

Answer (score 51):

Yes, we can zip and unzip the file/folder using cmd. See the below command and simply you can copy past in cmd and change the directory and file name

**To Zip/Compress File**
`powershell Compress-Archive D:\Build\FolderName D:\Build\FolderName.zip`

**To Unzip/Expand File**
`powershell expand-archive D:\Build\FileName.zip D:\deployments\FileName`

Comment: This syntax doesn't work if you're trying to zip more than one item. The microsoft reference for the cmdlet: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive

Comment: Still it will work, that all you have to do is, just go to parent folder and try to zip entire folder so automatically all the items inside the folder will automatically zip, Hope it help... just try once.

Comment: Compress-Archive relies upon the Microsoft .NET Framework API only work when files less than 2 GB... Reference --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/50418594/1371297 
:(

Comment: great command thx

Comment: It might be helpful to mention `Compress-Archive` is only available in power shell V5 and up

Comment: For windows this should be the no 1 answer

Comment: Does not seem to work if the pathname contains spaces.  Try enclosing with both double and single quotes but neither made a difference.

Answer (score 21):

You can use the following command:

```
zip -r nameoffile.zip directory
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: am using windows XP. The command zip is not recognized as internal or external command. Can you suggest me in windows XP?

Comment: This will not be platform independent. I think OP wants to do it using java.

Answer (score 13):

Windows 10 has tar command since 2018. It supports zip archive in default. You do not need to install any additional packages nor software.

```
tar.exe acvf yourfile.zip yourfolder
```

Compress-Archive in PowerShell does not support 2GB+ files.

Comment: This worked great for me. Note that Windows actually ships bsdtar. An list of all command line options can be found here: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bsdtar&sektion=1&format=html
The options acvf in the answer mean:

  -a - autodetect archive type from extension .zip
  -c - create a new archive
  -v - verbose
  -f - next command line parameter is the name of the archive that should be created

Comment: Is this really a `.ZIP` file? Or is it a compressed tar archive? Experimentation could tell the answer eventually...

Answer (score 5):

The zip Package should be installed in system.

## To Zip a File

```
zip <filename.zip> <file>
```

Example:

```
zip doc.zip doc.txt
```

## To Unzip a File

```
unzip <filename.zip>
```

Example:

```
unzip mydata.zip
```

Comment: I assume that works on Linux, but it doesn't work on Windows. Of course, the OP didn't mention which operating system he was using.

Comment: This answer is not well-formed. Does "The zip Package should be installed in system" mean you need to install it first? Or that you should expect it to already be installed?

Answer (score 2):

At the time of the Original Question the correct answer should have been use Windows JScript or VBS via command line which at the time such methods could build upto 2 GB zip using ADODB.Stream.writeFile(destination,ZIP_DATA);

[image]

for a modernised copy  which still works well in Windows 10 see https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/zipjs.bat

### **The CMD tool for zip handling on newer Windows 10,
and carried over to Win 11 is TAR**,

however it was not "native" command line in Windows 8 or earlier, since that system inbuilt dll feature was there as part of explorer, since I think, at least XP"

see `Tar --help`

To list use `Tar -tf file.zip`

To extract use `Tar -m -xf file.zip`

So the OP wanted save to zip

**To compress use `Tar -a -cf new.zip files`**

Other options are available, but I think to work with "nested" archive files requires peeling the levels off.
For a practical use you can extract images and thumbnails or text from zips such as MS DocX, PptX, etc.
[image]

Overall it is better to use a universal zip tool such as the prime suggestion  7-Zip utility, but others are popular on windows especially the  Grandfather of all Windows variants WinZip (c) 1991 https://www.winzip.com/en/download/winzip/ which has specialist versions such as secured WinZip Courier and WinZip PDF!

Answer (score 1):

Zip the folder from cmd by running PowerShell:

```
powershell "Add-Type -A System.IO.Compression.FileSystem; [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory('folder','archive.zip')"
```

Unzip:

```
powershell "Add-Type -A System.IO.Compression.FileSystem; [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory('archive.zip','folder')"
```

Answer (score -1):

Nothing listed here worked with me. This should be a very simple thing. I post my answer here, if anything because each time I search for "how to zip on the cmd window" I end up on this page, with no solution that works for me.

So here is the one that works with me: `zip output_file input_files`, as in the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: You don't say what problems you had with other commands, but several suggest pretty much what you've shown there.  The only differences I can see are that you've omitted `-r`, and not put the optional `.zip` extension on your filename.