# Using XCOPY to copy files in a Zipped folder Not Working

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to copy files from a path which is like as shown below

```
D:\XXX\XXX\SXX_FX.zip\ADMIN
```

By using code...

```
@echo off 
Rem This is for copy down all the files in the directory 

set origin=D:\NXG\Backup_Prod\SGL_FINANCE\WebFolder\SGL_FINANCE.zip\ADMINAPP
set drive=D:\TEST3
set d1=%date:~4,2%
set d2=%date:~7,2%
set d3=%date:~10,4%

XCOPY "%origin%" "%drive%_%d1%%d2%%d3%.zip*" /s /Y
echo "The program has completed"
```

But I am getting the error message. `File not found - ADMIN`.
Is it because I am trying to open the zipped file while copying.

Could you please throw some light on how to unzip that folder on the fly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks minimum understanding.

Comment: Your system includes a "zip folders" extension that lets you work *from explorer* as if zip files were folders. This extension is not usable from command line, so, you will need some tool or script to unzip the required file. From  `xcopy` point of view,  zip files are files, not folders.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch file script to zip files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485419/batch-file-script-to-zip-files)

Answer (score 0):

Using 7zip
Take a "**file.txt**" from "**Archive.zip**" to "**Destination\Folder**"

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e -ir!file.txt "C:\Path\To\Archive.zip" -o"C:\Path\to\Destination\Folder\"
```