# Make zip file using bat script without using other app

Tags: windows, batch-file, zip

I created batch file creating db backup file, that is working fine. In the point of memory allocation its required more space. so i need to make zip after sql creation. also i don't want to install other applications like 7-Zip. first thing it is possible to do make zip without using external application. 
creation of zip using batch file already asked. but i want to do both action in same batch scripts.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/how-can-i-compress-zip-and-uncompress-unzip-files-and-folders-with-bat

Comment: @npocmaka: Wow not bad, this is also a possibility using Visual basic script in batch: https://superuser.com/a/112094

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485419/batch-file-script-to-zip-files

Comment: @S.G.: That solution assumes that you have a `zip` command in your prompt.

Comment: @npocmaka i already seen this question. ZIP.CMD is not worked when i run this command.

Comment: @AndreKampling ,@s.g i searched but i didn't get answer for making one batch file create and make zip that file

Comment: please show answer related to this question. people simply put as duplicate.,

Comment: @Balasubramanian: It is explained in the link I've posted: https://superuser.com/a/112094. It is very straight forward. There should be no reason why this isn't working for you.

Comment: @Balasubramanian - have you ran the script as admin? Do you have certutil on your machine?