# Cannot run npm install browserify

Tags: installation, npm, browserify

I try to run `npm install browserify` both locally and globally (`-g`)

but I always got the follow errors

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package bn.js does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer miller-rabin@1.1.2 wants bn.js@^0.16.0

npm ERR! System Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "browserify"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/kanitw/Dropbox/_Projects/_idl/_visrec/vegalite
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.24
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.21
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/kanitw/Dropbox/_Projects/_idl/_visrec/vegalite/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Not sure how to solve it.

(My node version is v0.10.24, I'm on OSX Yosemite)

Comment: same issue for me too

Answer (score 3):

In order to make the `workaround` work, you have to

1. Delete the existing `node_modules` folder.
2. `npm install miller-rabin@1.1.1 --save-peer`
3. `npm install browserify`

That works guaranteed.

Answer (score 2):

This commit introduced the breaking change: https://github.com/indutny/miller-rabin/commit/bb85f555974587a410a17173f0bc484133b53cb7

The author of the library should fix it, but meanwhile you can:

1. Delete the existing `node_modules` folder
2. `npm install miller-rabin@1.1.1 --save-peer`
3. `npm install browserify`

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue on Linux. Try running    `npm update -g`
before installing browserify. This has worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Recently found this issue on browserify's github.

https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/1049

There is a workaround described.

Answer (score 0):

There are details of a workaround list in the issues on the github page

[Error listing](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/1049)

To summarise the solution posted in the issue, you need to install miller-rabin@1.1.1 as a peer-dependency in your own project (npm install miller-rabin@1.1.1 --save-peer) that makes sure the bn.js@0.15 is used rather than the more recent version.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try zipping your existing node_modules and package.json, then delete them.

You may need to 1st generate a new package.json using:

```
npm init
```

Then install browserify locally:

`npm install browserify`

Also, you'll have to install browserify globally:

```
npm install browserify -g
```

To zip on CMD or terminal refer to the following article:

[How to zip a file using cmd line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180060/how-to-zip-a-file-using-cmd-line)