# Index handler is undefined or not exported

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cli

I have a lambda function which was working fine but I wanted to import a package so I created a directory with index.js and installed my npm package.

Then created a zip of this folder and uploaded it using

> aws lambda update-function-code --function-name smrtfac-test
>   --zip-file fileb://lambda.zip

But now I am getting this error

```
index.handler is undefined or not exported
```

What could be the reason for it?
my `index.js` and `node_modules` are in the same directory.

Comment: For me, it was an issue with the function's case, I forgot to change one char to uppercase

Answer (score 141, accepted):

This usually occurs when you zip up the directory, instead of zipping up the contents of the directory. When you open your zip file to browse the content, the index.js file should be in the root of the zip file, not in a folder.

Comment: Command I used to fix the issue (run from within the directory): zip -r -D lambda.zip *

Comment: This worked for me, but I had a lot of symlinks in my bin directory all pointing back to image magick and without the -y flag it ended up being way too large for lambda. So yeah... include the -y flag.

Comment: Since zip doesn't work In windows, I use the commands mentioned in this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/64475079/8810941, to zip and unzip the content. Sure, it has some limitations but is more than enough for zipping a lambda function.

Comment: @Pavindu I would recommend using WSL for this sort of thing if you are on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 18):

You could also change the Handler section as below if your index.js is not directly under root folder as below

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Consider using Lambda Layers for node modules: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path

Answer (score 4):

If you're using typescript with CDK, make sure you are not exporting another function within your main function file.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are probably submitting the project inside a directory. You just zip all the files directly instead of zipping them into a directory. The index file needs to be at the root to be able to be read and accessed by lambda.

Answer (score 0):

I was using colima and after trying a bunch of things, I did:

```
colima delete
colima start
```

colima doc : [link](https://github.com/abiosoft/colima#upgrading)

In the lambda project's root directory, do these commands again and all should be ok

```
sam build
sam local invoke
```

At the very least, a hello-world project should work. You can use `sam init` to build a hello-world app and run a basic check.