# How to reference handler in Terraform for a Lambda on S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

My lambda is in a zip archive on S3, and I have deployed both the lambda and an API Gateway on AWS.

Here's what I have in my project root folder:

- `index.js` (entrypoint)
- `package.json`
- `README.md`
- `node_modules`
- `build.sh` (a bash script that executes `npm install` and `zip -r project-folder .`)

`index.js` is the entry point, within the file, I'm using https://github.com/spring-media/aws-lambda-router to handle the routing:

```
exports.handler = router.handler({
    proxyIntegration: {
        routes: [
            <routes_defined>
        ]
    }
})
```

In my terraform infrastructure below (redacted many resources parameters for simplicity), I am creating a lambda resource using a module and feeding in the handler to be `index.handler` and references my S3 bucket. All the other resources are related to the API gateway and permission between the gateway and the lambda:

```
module "module_name" {
  handler            = "index.handler"
  s3_bucket          = <references_s3_bucket>
}


resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "api_gateway"
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api_policy" "api_gateway_policy" 
resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "proxy"

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_api_gateway" 

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "proxy" 
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "api_gateway_integration" 
resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "api_gateway_deploy" 
resource "aws_api_gateway_stage" "api_gateway_stage" 
resource "aws_api_gateway_api_key" "api_gateway_key" 
resource "aws_api_gateway_usage_plan" "api_gateway_usage_plan" 
resource "aws_api_gateway_usage_plan_key" "api_gateway_usage_plan_key"
```

Now this doesn't show anything wrong upon deployment, until I actually test the API gateway on my AWS console. When I issue a request to the API gateway, it responds with an error of `index.js is undefined or not exported`. What seems to be the issue? I've made sure that the `index.js` is in the root folder as described in this issue: [Index handler is undefined or not exported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60665901/index-handler-is-undefined-or-not-exported)

Answer (score 0):

Oh well, I think the setup of `index.handler` is correct, I simply missed out on the part where we had aliases setup, and my correct version wasn't set to active. Everything worked once I bumped my version to the active one :D