# AWS Lambda function in Step function returns "Runtime.HandlerNotFound"

Tags: node.js, json, amazon-web-services, api, ifttt

**Problem:**
When I try to run a Step Function (with Lambda functions) I am given this error message:

```
Runtime.HandlerNotFound in step: SolarEdgeOvervie
```

**Cause** >

```json
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.HandlerNotFound",
  "errorMessage": "index.handler is undefined or not exported",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.HandlerNotFound: index.handler is undefined or not exported",
    "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:144:11)",
    "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)",
    "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)",
    "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)",
    "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)",
    "    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)",
    "    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"
  ]
}

// Task failed by SolarEdgeOverview 

{
  "resourceType": "lambda",
  "resource": "invoke",
  "error": "Runtime.HandlerNotFound",
  "cause": {
    "errorType": "Runtime.HandlerNotFound",
    "errorMessage": "index.handler is undefined or not exported",
    "trace": [
      "Runtime.HandlerNotFound: index.handler is undefined or not exported",
      "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:144:11)",
      "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)",
      "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)",
      "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)",
      "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)",
      "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)",
      "    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)",
      "    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"
    ]
  }
}

// Excution failed

{
  "error": "Runtime.HandlerNotFound",
  "cause": {
    "errorType": "Runtime.HandlerNotFound",
    "errorMessage": "index.handler is undefined or not exported",
    "trace": [
      "Runtime.HandlerNotFound: index.handler is undefined or not exported",
      "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:144:11)",
      "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)",
      "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)",
      "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)",
      "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)",
      "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)",
      "    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)",
      "    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have used a default setup, I think.

I suspect that I haven’t set up the Step-Function correctly or when I did some research into the error I might not have given sufficient permission to the “index.handler” or Zip etc.

Comment: Do you have index.js file in the root folder for each lambda functions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60665901/index-handler-is-undefined-or-not-exported

Comment: Welcome to SO!  @ArpitJain had a good suggestion.  Also, it's considered a good SO practice to add the first few lines of your Lambda function code to the question.  Not a code dump, just the minimum.

Comment: @ArpitJain How would I go around checking that, and if necessary fixing it as I can’t find how to do on the internet ? -Edit: Spelling

Comment: @Pilgrim, you can check in aws lambda console and select your function, and then there will be a `code` tab:- https://console.aws.amazon.com/lambda/home. You can read this page from aws to get the basic understanding on aws lamdas:- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

The best way to fix this problem for good is to use  an automated tool like `serverless` and let the tool handle the folder structure and deployment for you.
checkout this [link](https://www.serverless.com/)

Comment: I would like to solve the problem at hand so that I can follow the tutorial and I have invested quite a bit of time into this. But if it comes to worse, I will try this method.